# How to create a reference to existing Object? Especially for one of Get-Service object?

Tags: c#, powershell

```
$myService = get-service -Name Spool*
```

If I try to change service status, my variable is not change in my case. How to create a ref for a concrete obj?

Comment: You need to get the status **again** after changing it using `Get-Service`. Why do you think the variable `$myService` would change anyway?

Comment: Yes, but i want to create variable that LINK to realtime service object?

Comment: To change the status of a service, you need to use the [`Set-Service`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/set-service) cmdlet

Answer (score 2):

When you use `Get-Service`, you get an object containing all kinds of properties from that service **at the time the cmdlet ran**, like `Status`.

If after that you change the status of that service, the variable used to capture the status before is not altered automagically.

Therefore you have to run `Get-Service` again to refresh that information.

Comment: I understand, my variable is only an runtime instance, i would  like to create a class with field that have a reference for realtime object of services? how to create Link to realtime object??

Comment: @FletcherF1 You can't, unless you write a service of your own that constantly pulls the status of some other service.